# Not supported exception in LINQ Lambda

Tags: c#, linq, exception, lambda

I have this code and it gives me this following error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method"

```
var AuxiliarValue = _context.company.LastOrDefault(x => x.StartValue.HasValue && (x.StartValue.Value < InicialValue));
```

InicialValue is `Double`

But when I put a `ToList()`, it works

```
var AuxiliarValue = _context.company.ToList().LastOrDefault(x => x.StartValue.HasValue && (x.StartValue.Value < InicialValue));
```

Can anyone explain to me why it works with `ToList()`?

Comment: You should probably include more of the error, but I do know that `LastOrDefault` is generally not supported.  You need to use `.OrderByDescending` in conjunction with `.FirstOrDefault`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`LastOrDefault` is not supported with LINQ to Entities. You can use `OrderByDescending` and then use `FirstOrDefault`

```
var AuxiliarValue = _context.company
                        .OrderByDescending(r=> yourFieldtoOrder)
                        .FirstOrDefault(x => x.StartValue.HasValue && (x.StartValue.Value < InicialValue));
```

The reason it works with `ToList` is that `ToList` will iterate all the results and bring them in memory, so the `LastOrDefault` is executed on an in-memory collection, rather than at the database end.

Answer (score 2):

It works when you add `ToList` because the query is no longer being translated into SQL and executed by the database.  Instead, the entire table of data is returned from the database to your application, a `List` is built to hold that data, and then the operation is performed using LINQ to Objects.

You probably don't want to do that; you probably want to adjust the way that you query the data such that it can be translated into SQL and run against the database.